# Change img src when browser hits 1440px using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am needed to change an image source for when the browser is at 1440px+. Currently I have code that does this but when I move the browser window BACK to less than 1440px, the image source stays at the source for 1440px, and does not fluctuate back to the "original" source.

```
const reswidth = screen.width;
let image = document.querySelector(".future__container--img");
if (reswidth >= 1440) {
  image.src = "../images/illustration-editor-desktop.svg";
} else {
  image.src = "../images/illustration-editor-mobile.svg";
}
```

any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For that to happen you have to add a `resize` event listener to `window` and call the code inside. You can also use CSS though (by having both images in your HTML and hiding one of them using media rules)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset

Answer (score 1):

Heres a modification of your js:

```js
function resizeImg() {
  const reswidth = screen.width;
  let image = document.querySelector(".future__container--img");
  console.log(image.src);
  if (reswidth >= 1400) {
    image.src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300";
  } else {
    image.src = "https://placekitten.com/g/200/300";
  }
}
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeImg);
```

```html
<img class="future__container--img" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="image 1"></img>
```

Comment: Prosy, once again.. thank you.. you are a legend!

Comment: OMG haha. I hadn't noticed! And you haven't accepted any of my answers so far :(

Comment: Sorry I am new in using stackoverflow, looking into it now